# How can I include multiple php files into a wordpress page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created content that goes through a database and accesses information to then display it in multiple test files.  I want to migrate this over to a page on a wordpress website.  I have created a custom page page-slug.php and have inserted code for the basic html part, which is working fine, however I am having trouble getting the other php files it needs to access recognized by the include statements.  It is working perfect when I have all of the files just displaying the content on the test url.  I just need it to access the files such as connect.php, query.php, etc.  I have placed the files into the wordpress custom theme folder as well.  I also need the file to reference a couple jquery files as well as my php ones.

Comment: go to wordpress documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what is the situation and I have the feeling you have to fill up some gray areas in your understanding of how wordpress works basically - topics like enqueuing scripts and css files, using actions and filters (google it and try it), but:

1. In order to including JS / CSS files, use:
   wp_enqueue_script ([link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script))
   wp_enqueue_style ([link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style))

You have to use the "add_action" call in your functions.php file for a start (later on you can make a separate functions file)

2. If you want to load php files inline, you can use for example the **get_template_part** function

You really have to learn about these basic topics first:
actions & filters / hooks, which are something like events / triggers in other systems
enqueuing files to wordpress
customizing your wordpress template
creating a child theme - important